# MySQL delete join with multiple ON fields

Tags: mysql

I'm having issues creating a statement to delete records with a join on multiple fields. I've searched and found many solutions, that are not working for me still.

I have two tables:
orders.profile and orders.qualified

There isn't a simple one single field to join between, but multiple. Essentially based on the customers needs some of the items stored in their profile may not qualify based on geography, so they need to be removed.

Here's what I've been playing with, currently I'm getting UNKNOWN TABLE error, when I remove the database from the table definition at the beginning, I get a NO DATABASE SELECTED error.

```
DELETE FROM orders.profile
USING orders.profile AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders.qualified AS q
ON p.cust_id = q.cust_id
AND p.job_number = q.job_number
AND p.job_seg = q.job_seg
AND p.zip = q.zip
AND p.carrier_route = q.carrier_route
WHERE p.cust_id = {the cust_id in question}
AND p.job_number = {the job number in question}
and q.qualified = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer from Holger Brandt I was able to get this working by defining the database and the alias.

So the query should look like this:

```
DELETE orders.p
FROM orders.profile AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders.qualified AS q
ON p.cust_id = q.cust_id
AND p.job_number = q.job_number
AND p.job_seg = q.job_seg
AND p.zip = q.zip
AND p.carrier_route = q.carrier_route
WHERE p.cust_id = {the cust_id in question}
AND p.job_number = {the job number in question}
and q.qualified = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the delete without the `USING` statement:

```
DELETE p FROM
orders.profile AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN orders.qualified AS q
  ON p.cust_id = q.cust_id ...
```

If this doesn't work, there is something more fundamental going on.

Comment: I get no database selected... and I've read multiple places specifically saying you can't use the alias when deleting with multiple rows.

Comment: @Jeff, I edited the answer.  If it doesn't work, something more fundamental is going one.  Also, does `orders.profile` have a primary key?

Comment: Ok I think I got it. The database needs to be defined, and the alias MUST be used.

Comment: Also, no primary keys in either table.

Comment: @Jeff, Great to hear.  Good luck with the project.

Comment: Thanks for the help Holger. For anyone stumbling: `DELETE orders.p FROM orders.profile AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN orders.qualified AS q ON p.cust_id = q.cust_id ...`

Comment: @Jeff, You might want to add your own answer so others can see what worked.  You won't get any reputation but others will easily see the final outcome.